# Is there exist the integral of the consine integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there exist integral of the consine integral?

http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=dc816cd78d306d7bda61f6facf5f17f7

When i input $\int ci(x) dx$ into the calculator, it says no results found in terms of standard mathematical functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply put,
$$\int \text{Ci}(x)dx=x\text{Ci}(x)-\sin x+C\\
\implies \int \text{Ci}(x)dx=x\int\dfrac{\cos x}{x}dx-\sin x+C$$

Answer (score 1):

$\int ci(x) dx = xci(x) - sin(x) + C$
I found the problem. You need to capitalize the c. Your input should be $\int Ci(x)dx$. Wolfram uses mathematica, keyword begins with capital letters.